# gpg key mismatch when importing

Tags: server, gnupg, keyserver

I am trying to import a specific key from ubuntu key server and when I launch the gpg command for that, the received key ID does not match the one I passed as argument:

```
$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 54404762BBB6E853
gpg: key A48449044AAD5C5D: 4 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: clef A48449044AAD5C5D : « Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (11/bullseye) <ftpmaster@debian.org> » n'est pas modifiée
gpg:       Quantité totale traitée : 1
gpg:                 non modifiées : 1
```

I requested the: **54404762BBB6E853** but received **A48449044AAD5C5D**. Deleting and reimporting the key gives the same behavior

**Edit**: this behaviour is totally normal. A subkey is bound to his primary key. You will need to pass `--with-subkey-fingerprints` to `apt-key` in order to print its fingerprint. I did not notice the "sub" comming with "pub" entries. My bad.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Accepting an answer if it solved your problem is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key you are importing can be seen on the Ubuntu keyserver HTTP interface:

- http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0xa48449044aad5c5d&fingerprint=on&op=index

Here you can see that the key you're requesting is actually [a *subkey*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76940/what-exactly-is-a-subkey) of the one you're getting:

```
uid Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (11/bullseye) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sig  sig  a48449044aad5c5d 2021-01-17T11:17:04Z 2029-01-15T11:17:04Z ____________________ [selfsig]
sig  sig  dc30d7c23cbbabee 2021-01-17T11:26:41Z ____________________ ____________________ dc30d7c23cbbabee
sig  sig  4dfab270caa96dfa 2021-01-17T11:27:03Z ____________________ ____________________ 4dfab270caa96dfa
sig  sig  73a4f27b8dd47936 2021-01-17T11:29:50Z ____________________ ____________________ 73a4f27b8dd47936
sig  sig  bc372252ca1cf964 2021-01-17T11:42:26Z ____________________ ____________________ bc372252ca1cf964
sig  sig  db16cf5bb12525c4 2021-01-17T12:51:55Z ____________________ ____________________ db16cf5bb12525c4

sub rsa4096/ed541312a33f1128f10b1c6c54404762bbb6e853 2021-01-17T11:17:04Z            
sig sbind a48449044aad5c5d 2021-01-17T11:17:04Z ____________________ 2029-01-15T11:17:04Z []
```

My understanding is that [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Subkeys) does this so that one key can be used for signing while the other key can be kept offline.

Comment: We are running a local mirror of ubuntu and debian archives and the debian part is poping up many of the following error: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853.
What am is supposed to do if I cannot get the 54404762BBB6E853 ? is there any additional command I have to do?

Comment: where can I find the 54404762BBB6E853?